# Drag and drop: Draggable append to droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I have a project http://jsfiddle.net/x5T4h/566/ .

html:

```
<div class="dropable base">
  <div class="draggable">Div1</div>
  <div class="draggable">Div2</div>
  <div class="draggable">Div3</div>
  <div class="draggable">Div4</div>
</div>

<div class="places">
    <div class="droppable">Move here div</div>
  <div class="droppable">Move here div</div>
  <div class="droppable">Move here div</div>
  <div class="droppable">Move here div</div>
</div>
```

jQuery UI:

```
$('.droppable').droppable({ tolerance: "touch" });
$('.draggable').draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
$('.base').droppable();
```

I want to:

1. Make draggable appended to droppable when it is dropped. I tried to
   use helper and appendTo function, but it does not work that way I
   was looking for. I want make dropped draggable the same position and
   same size as that droppable (excepted class .base). It should look like the draggable lays
   on the droppable at same possition. I tried everything.
2. Only one draggable can be dropped to one droppable.

I tried everything, but it still did not work like I expected.

Comment: Do you want the "slot" that the draggable is pulled from to remain? Should the dropped element be made draggable again? It is not clear what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this and it's not entirely clear what you're looking for in your question. Here my suggestion.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/x5T4h/568/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).append(ui.draggable);
      $(this).find(".draggable").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        margin: "-1px",
        width: $(this).width() + "px"
      });
      $(e.target).droppable("disable");
    }
  });
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 1000
  });
  $('.base').droppable();
});
```

Hope that helps.